# How can I save the material of the player with playerprefs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game wehre you are a cube and you dodge obstacles, I just implemented the ability to change the color of the cube like changing skin. I did that by assigning a different material to the player when he presses "2".

Here is the script:

```
 void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
    {
        Object.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = Material1;
    }
}
```

When you die the scene resets and when you win a new scene is loaded, I would like the game to remember the material change even after the scene is reset or a new scene is loaded. I have done some research and found something called "PlayerPrefs" and I have been playing around with it but nothing even got close to working and I didn't really understand what i was doing.

I really want to understand how this works becuase I know i will be using it alot when making games. Can someone help me understand?

Thanks.

Comment: Best way would probably be to have a global materials "catalogue" (`Dictionary<int, Material>`) and only store the current `int` index in the PlayerPrefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one gameobject and apply this script

```
public class SavingMaterial : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static SavingMaterial instance;

  public Material mat;

  void Awake()
  {
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(base.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(base.gameObject);
    }
  }

  public void StoreMaterial(MeshRenderer mesh)
  {
    mat = mesh.material;
  }
}
```

When you want to store material call this function like this

```
SavingMaterial.instance.StoreMaterial(you meshrenderer component);
```

and when you need this material just get from this class like this

```
material = SavingMaterial.instance.mat;
```

and note that if you quit the game you loose saved material as it is store in variable otherwise scene change and reset won't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

you only save int,string and bool in playerprefs. you have to store values of materials into string and then save this string into playerprefs.

alternatively you can assign this material to local variable and set that script on Dontdestroyonload so it will not reset as scene is destroy or reset.

Comment: Could you please add a code example, I dont know how to assign the material to a local variable. Maybe im just stupid.